# use column name as condition for where on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following DataFrame:

```
arrays = [['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'],
          ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))          
columnValues = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns = columnValues)
print(df)

             foo                 bar          
               A         B         C         D
0       0.037362  0.470010  0.315396  0.333798
1       0.339038  0.396307  0.487242  0.064883
2       0.691654  0.793609  0.044490  0.384154
3       0.605801  0.967021  0.156839  0.123816
```

I want to produce the following output:

```
             foo                 bar          
               A         B         C         D
0              0         0  0.315396  0.333798
1              0         0  0.487242  0.064883
2              0         0  0.044490  0.384154
3              0         0  0.156839  0.123816
```

I think I can use `pd.DataFrame.where()` for this, however I don't see how to pass the column name `bar` as a condition.

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to specifically use `bar` instead of `foo` to produce the desired outcome, as `foo` would actually be many columns

EDIT2: Unfortunately list comprehension breaks if the list contains all the column labels. Explicitly writing out the for loop does work though.
So instead of this:

```
df.loc[:,  [col for col in df.columns.levels[0] if col != 'bar']] = 0
```

I use this:

```
for col in df.columns.levels[0]:
    if not(col in nameList):
        df.loc[:,col]=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [slicing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to set your data. Here, you could access sub-columns (A, B), under `foo`.

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
        foo                 bar
          A         B         C         D
0  0.040251  0.119267  0.170111  0.582362
1  0.978192  0.592043  0.515702  0.630627
2  0.762532  0.667234  0.450505  0.103858
3  0.871375  0.397503  0.966837  0.870184

In [13]: df.loc[:, 'foo'] = 0

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
  foo          bar
    A  B         C         D
0   0  0  0.170111  0.582362
1   0  0  0.515702  0.630627
2   0  0  0.450505  0.103858
3   0  0  0.966837  0.870184
```

If you want to set all columns except `bar`, you could do.

```
In [15]: df.loc[:,  [col for col in df.columns.levels[0] if col != 'bar']] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. While this produces the desired result for the example above, in practice I'd rather use `bar` as a condition than `foo`, as `foo` actually would be many columns.

Comment: something like `df.loc[:,  [col for col in df.columns.levels[0] if col != 'bar']] = 0`?

Comment: Ended up using this approach, as it allowed me to pass a list too, e.g. `['A', 'B']` instead of `'bar'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get_level_values`, I guess:

```
>>> df
        foo                 bar          
          A         B         C         D
0  0.039728  0.065875  0.825380  0.240403
1  0.617857  0.895751  0.484237  0.506315
2  0.332381  0.047287  0.011291  0.346073
3  0.216224  0.024978  0.834353  0.500970
>>> df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(0) != "bar"] = 0
>>> df
  foo          bar          
    A  B         C         D
0   0  0  0.825380  0.240403
1   0  0  0.484237  0.506315
2   0  0  0.011291  0.346073
3   0  0  0.834353  0.500970
```

`df.columns.droplevel(1) != "bar"` should also work, although I don't like it as much even though it's shorter because it inverts the selection logic.

Answer (score 0):

Easier, without loc

> df['foo'] = 0

Comment: It is advised when setting values in a pandas object, care must be taken to avoid what is called [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Comment: Where are you seeing a chain? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you happen not to have this multi index you can use:

```
df.ix[:,['A','B']] = 0
```

This replaces automatically the values in your columns 'A' and 'B' by 0.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Cause i've used this method many times and it works quite well.
But never with a multi-index, not that i can recall at least.

Comment: just create a DF from the question and run your code against it - you'll see. Why would you answer this question if you have never tried it yourself ?

Comment: Did you at least read my answer? first line: "If you happen not to have this multi index you can use"
Why would you comment this answer if you have never read it yourself?

Comment: ah, OK, i guess your answer has helped OP a LOT... :)